# Biblatex changing 'and' string in titles!

Tags: biblatex, biber

I just came across an example of biblatex changing the value of the string "and" in the name of a publisher (changing it from "and" to "et"). I would expect this to be the case in fields like Authors, Editors, ... but not in the name of a Publisher. Anyone know the reason for that? And what other strings get changed in the same way?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage[language=french]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {pontryagin,
    AUTHOR = {Pontryagin, L. S.},
     TITLE = {Topological groups},
 PUBLISHER = {Gordon and Breach Science Publishers, Inc.},
      YEAR = {1966},
     PAGES = {xv+543},
  LANGUAGE = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{p.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a test, \parencite{pontryagin}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is normal,  "publisher" is a list field and is parsed, taking "and" as separator. Use "{and}" instead.

Comment: Is this the only string?

Comment: "and" has special meaning in list and name fields. If you want biblatex to understand it literally, you must wrap it in braces. I've tested it here, and will write an answer, even though this is likely a duplicate.

Comment: Paulo Ney, I've added some info in the answer regarding where you can check the characteristics of each field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"and" has special meaning in list and name fiels, and is understood as the separator between its itens. As you wrote `PUBLISHER = {Gordon and Breach Science Publishers, Inc.},` biblatex understood that you have two publishers "Gordon" and "Breach Science Publishers, Inc.". And when it wrote them in your reference, it wrote it as a list of two items, receiving the appropriate delimiter for the language in use "et".

If you want an "and" to be understood literally (that is, not a list separator), you must wrap it in braces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage[language=french]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {pontryagin,
    AUTHOR = {Pontryagin, L. S.},
     TITLE = {Topological groups},
 PUBLISHER = {Gordon {and} Breach Science Publishers, Inc.},
      YEAR = {1966},
     PAGES = {xv+543},
  LANGUAGE = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a test, \parencite{pontryagin}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Giving now the expected result:

[image]

Biblatex's [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) describes its data types in section 2.2.1, those being "Name lists" (such as author and editor), "Literal lists" (such as publisher and location), "Literal fields", "Range fields", "Integer fields" and so on. On the following section, the documentation describes all the data fields, and for each of them, you have the information of the corresponding data type. For publisher, we have "publisher: list (literal)".

As to how literal lists are dealt with, the documentation says:

> Literal lists are parsed and split up into the individual items at the `and` delimiter but not dissected further. Literal lists may be truncated in the `bib` file with the keyword 'and others'.